# akka http client system.shutdown() produce "Outgoing request stream error (akka.stream.AbruptTerminationException)" when using https

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

Hi the following code works as expected.

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

import system.dispatcher

val request = HttpRequest(uri = "http://www.google.com")

Http.get(system).singleRequest(request).map(_.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore))
  .onComplete { _ =>
    println("shutting down actor system...")
    system.terminate()
  }
```

However, if I change http://www.google.com to https://www.google.com like the following:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

import system.dispatcher

val request = HttpRequest(uri = "https://www.google.com")

Http.get(system).singleRequest(request).map(_.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore))
  .onComplete { _ =>
    println("shutting down actor system...")
    system.terminate()
  }
```

I get the following error message:

```
shutting down actor system...
[ERROR] [02/11/2017 13:13:08.929] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Outgoing request stream error (akka.stream.AbruptTerminationException)
```

Anyone knows why https produces above error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is apparently a known issue, see the following tickets:

- [akka-http#497](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/497)
- [akka#18747](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18747)

The error seems harmless.